# Sampling rate too slow

Tags: arduino-nano, accelerometer

I have an Arduino Nano connected to an Adafruit H3LIS331 accelerometer. The sampling is initiated by a button press, which sets a delay to prepare for the measurement, and then the sampling begins. The defined sampling rate is 1 kHz. However, when reading the values from the serial monitor using PySerial, I get approximately 350 samples per second.

Code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_H3LIS331.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

// Button pin
#define SWITCH 8

const unsigned long REPETITION_INTERVAL = 1000; // repetition time in milliseconds, 6000ms is 6 seconds

// Initiate H3LIS331 library
Adafruit_H3LIS331 lis = Adafruit_H3LIS331();

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);          // Open Serial Monitor
  while (!Serial) delay(10);     

  if (! lis.begin_I2C()) {
    Serial.println("Couldnt start H3LIS331 sensor!");
    while (1) yield();
  }

  Serial.println("H3LIS331 found!");

  lis.setRange(H3LIS331_RANGE_400_G);   // Set range of possibe 100, 200, or 400 G! In our case 400g
  Serial.print("Range set to: ");

  switch (lis.getRange()) {
    case H3LIS331_RANGE_100_G: Serial.println("100 g"); break;
    case H3LIS331_RANGE_200_G: Serial.println("200 g"); break;
    case H3LIS331_RANGE_400_G: Serial.println("400 g"); break;
  }

  lis.setDataRate(LIS331_DATARATE_1000_HZ);  // Set data rate/time resolution to 1000Hz
  Serial.print("Data rate set to: ");

  switch (lis.getDataRate()) {
    case LIS331_DATARATE_POWERDOWN: Serial.println("Powered Down"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_50_HZ: Serial.println("50 Hz"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_100_HZ: Serial.println("100 Hz"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_400_HZ: Serial.println("400 Hz"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_1000_HZ: Serial.println("1000 Hz"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_LOWPOWER_0_5_HZ: Serial.println("0.5 Hz Low Power"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_LOWPOWER_1_HZ: Serial.println("1 Hz Low Power"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_LOWPOWER_2_HZ: Serial.println("2 Hz Low Power"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_LOWPOWER_5_HZ: Serial.println("5 Hz Low Power"); break;
    case LIS331_DATARATE_LOWPOWER_10_HZ: Serial.println("10 Hz Low Power"); break;
  }
}

void loop() {
  int buttonPressed = digitalRead(SWITCH);

  // If the button pressed
  if (buttonPressed) {
    Serial.println("5 seconds preparation...");

    // Wait 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) for the measurement to take effect
    delay(5000);  
    
    Serial.println("Measurement Started");
    unsigned long startTime = millis() + REPETITION_INTERVAL;
    while(startTime >= millis()) {
      // Get a new sensor event, normalized
      sensors_event_t event;
      lis.getEvent(&event);
      
      // Based the range of the H3LIS331, display the results measured in g
      Serial.print("\t\tX:"); Serial.print(event.acceleration.x / SENSORS_GRAVITY_STANDARD);
      Serial.print(" \tY:"); Serial.print(event.acceleration.y / SENSORS_GRAVITY_STANDARD);
      Serial.print(" \tZ:"); Serial.println(event.acceleration.z / SENSORS_GRAVITY_STANDARD);
    }
    Serial.println("Measurement Ended");
  }
}
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: You can speed it up by not printing while you sample.

Comment: @StarCat Thanks! How can I save the data without printing it?

Comment: how do you save startTime?

Comment: please copy the content of the  serial monitor and paste it into your question ... format as code

Comment: @StarCat is likely correct. Also, understand millis() will eventually roll over and when it does your code will run for a long long time before exiting. Consider storing all your samples in an array and printing it out after sampling is completed.

Comment: Thaks you all for the comments. 
@starCat, i didn't mention that i do not have and sd card on the arduino nano. How can store the data?